# Sort queryset using two columns then paginate efficiently

Tags: python, django, sql-order-by, django-pagination

I've a `queryset` which I want to sort using one of the columns, say `date1`, and if the value of `date1` is `None` then use another column `date2` for sorting and if `date2` is also `None` then use `datetime.max`. So, this is what I came up with :

```
queryset = sorted(queryset, key= lambda row: row.date1 if row.date1 else row.date2 if row.date2 else datetime.max)
```

and then for paginating (with say 20 in one page) I'm sending back the `id` of last record of previous request and using that to get the next 20 items (since after sorting ids are now in in random order). Also the entries can be deleted by the users so, using `Paginator.page` and just fetching the consecutive pages in requests won't work.

This is how I find the index of the `lastRecord` for getting the next 20:

```
lastRecordIndex = next(i for (i, d) in enumerate(queryset) if d.id == lastRecord)
queryset = queryset[lastRecordIndex+1: lastRecordIndex+20+1]
```

So, the problem is that this approach works, but is way too slow. Is there anything better I can do? using raw query or something else in `django`?

Comment: First, this: `row.date1 if row.date1 else row.date2 if row.date2 else datetime.max` can be shortened to this: `row.date1 or row.date2 or datetime.max`

Comment: won't help with the performance still thanks for that @cwallenpoole

Comment: Wasn't saying it could. But it's less ugly.

Comment: actually the condition is different, i posted a simplified version here. it's like, `row.something.date1 if row.something else row.somethingelse.date2 if row.somethingelse else datetime.max` @cwallenpoole

Answer (score 1):

You could create your query with [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). Like this:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()\
        .annotate(date3=Case(
                When(date1__isnull=False, then='date1'),
                When(date2__isnull=False, then='date2'),
                default=Value(datetime.date.max), 
                output_field=DateField()
            )
        )\
        .order_by('date3')
```

A word of caution, though; this is only going to work if `date1` and `date2` are set to **null**. It will not work with blank. And it's also not going to be super fast, because each object in the queryset will be annotated, but at least the code is cleaner :)

Comment: considering the performance, i think it's going be the same as in case of my solution, except the cleaner part. also this doesn't answer the 2nd part of the question. thanks anyways.

Comment: First hit will probably be same or maybe even slower, but it will most likely be faster with pagination because most databases are caching table data. You can further improve performance with query caching.